# Azure App Service built-in authentication on gRPC

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, grpc, azure-authentication, grpc-c#

I deployed into Azure App Service a .NET 7 [sample hello gRPC API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) on Linux OS

```
public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;

    public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request,
        ServerCallContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {Name}", request.Name);
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply 
        {
            Message = "Hello " + request.Name
        });
    }
}
```

It is functioning properly and responding with the Hello greeting after I called it using Postman.

Now that I've attempted to use the built-in [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) functionality on Azure App Service with Microsoft Identity Platform, I haven't encountered any problems using Postman to call it without authentication.

Did you realize that gRPC is compatible with Azure App Service Authentication?

This is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
  }
}
```

and this the Program.cs

```
using GrpcGreeter.Services;
using System.Reflection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
// For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddGrpcReflection();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcReflectionService();
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

app.Run();
```

Comment: The [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) link which you have provided is for Web Applications.

Comment: Follow this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#secure-grpc-services-with-azure-ad-authentication) for Authentication and authorization in `gRPC`.

Comment: @Harshitha If the built-in authentication for gRPC on top of Azure App Service is not functioning, I will add it to the application as you suggested. What I'm attempting to determine is whether the out-of-the-box authentication option offered by Azure is effective for this use case.

Comment: `Did you realize that gRPC is compatible with Azure App Service Authentication?` Yes, `Azure App Service` Provides built-in authentication compatibility with `gRPC`.By default it uses `Azure Active Directory` as `Authentication Provider`.

Comment: @Harshitha it's not working in my case, the call it stuck forever after applied the built-in Authentication Provider and passing Authentication Bearer token to gRPC call.

Comment: Could you please share the code for Authentication which you have tried ?

Comment: @Harshitha I used the same example over here https://intellitect.com/blog/authenticate-without-code/ but instead to be a REST hello world it's a gRPC

Comment: Check this [link](https://dev.to/425show/secure-grpc-service-with-net-core-and-azure-active-directory-4p6k) once.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Harshitha The URL you provided is not the Azure App Service's built-in authentication. This code-based verification is compatible with gRPC, but it isn't what I'm attempting to confirm. I'm referring to built-in authentication using Azure without any integrated code.

Comment: Ok..Will check the link which you are following and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252529/discussion-between-harshitha-and-luigi-saggese).

Comment: No solution provided by @Harshitha. Still looking for an answer

Comment: Open issue on github repo https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/issues/167